# Internet Explorer margins or something else?

Tags: internet-explorer, web, doctype, margins

I making a website for a client that runs fine in firefox and chrome but not in explorer (all versions) explorer floats the website to left and margins get crazy.

i am completely clueless if its because of margins or something else and i must fix it asap else i will be in big trouble! i seriously need help.

This is what i have in my css body

```
body
{
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#fff;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

you can view the website [here](http://dreamworldtravelltd.com)

Please help me please.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have javascript in your page source before the opening doctype declaration.

This is throwing the site into quirks mode in IE. Move that script somewhere more appropriate (just before the closing tag of the body is the best place) and your problem will go away.

Comment: James South, Thank you so much this worked for me but the other issue appears is that the header (php) page disappears when the page loads the image slideshow banner, please mention where i am doing wrong.

Comment: You have an uncaught reference error in your page ~line 50. 
`$(window).load(function() {
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });`

Looks like something is interfering with your jQuery

Comment: GOSH! i've been trying to find the problem for so long but i am unable to find, i am using nivo slider with a jquery autocomplete i have also tried changing the jquerys but nothings works for ie8 any help please

Comment: It's hard to debug from here. I'd try commenting out the slider and see what happens. If that is definitely the cause you might want to seek an alternative. Remember Firebug is your friend when you want to find an error.

Comment: hi James thank you so much for being here, i did replaced nivo with some other jquery banner slideshow but the problem was still there so after a bit more searching on StackOverflow i fount the solution which is to add

jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

Thank you so much, i would like to contact you in future for further help when required, i hope you'll be there :)